# Find a matrix (in a base $B$) the projection operator of space $V$ on the subspace $\ker(F-I_{v})$ along the subspace $\ker(f-2I_{v})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$ B = (v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4})$$ - basis of the vector space V, F - linear operator on the $V$

$$M^{B}_{B} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}3&1&-1&1\\2&4&-1&-3\\2&2&0&-2\\2&2&-1&-1\end{array}\right]$$

Find a matrix (in a base $B$) the projection operator of space $V$ on the subspace $\ker(F-I_{v})$ along the subspace $\ker(f-2I_{v})$.

I need help how to do it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right then we should have the following. Let $P$ be the required projection operator and $x\in V$ be an arbitrary point. Then $Px\in\ker (F-I_v)$ and $x-Px\in\ker (F-2I_v)$. Then $(F-I_v)Px=0$ and $(F-2I_v)(x-Px)=0$. Hence $FPx=Px$ and $Fx-FPx-2x+2Px=0=Fx-2x+Px$. So $P=2I_v-F$.